# For a gas having molar mass M, express specific heat at constant pressure in terms of heat capacity ratio

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> For a gas having molar mass $M$, express specific heat at constant pressure in terms of heat capacity ratio.

My attempt:

using $ C_p  - C_V = R $ and

$ \dfrac{C_p}{C_V} = \gamma $

$ C_p = \dfrac{R \gamma }{ \gamma - 1} $

But answer is 
$ C_p = \dfrac{R \gamma }{ M(\gamma - 1)} $

But from where this $M$ is coming from? Isn't specific heat independent of $M$?

Comment: I agree with your answer.

Comment: The answer you've got $\left(C_p=\dfrac{\gamma R}{\gamma-1}\right)$ has the SI units $\dfrac{J}{mol\cdot K}$. The provided answer is in $\dfrac{J}{g\cdot K}$.